# Date From Timestamp Becomes Wrong

Tags: ios, swift, date, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert timestamp to Date. But it returns wrong date.

I have a time stamp

> 1524637838000.0

Which returns 25-04-2018 12:00 as per this [online converter](http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-5.5&timestamp=1524637838000.0&Submit=%20%20%20%20%20%20Convert%20to%20Date%20%20%20%20%20%20)

But I get wrong date when convert using my code

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:1524637838000.0)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"
    let myDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print("Date is = ",myDate)
```

I get

> 07-11-50283 12:03

as result. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it in millisecond or second precision?

Comment: @MadProgrammer milliseconds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your timestamp `1524637838000.0` in milliseconds, it should be in seconds, so your date initialization should be:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:(1524637838000.0/1000))
```

Comment: Yes, It Works!!